# In an extension, how to identify device orientation on iOS 10. It is not properly responding, or I am doing it wrong?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've tried multiple methods to add an observer, and call this function:

In viewDidLoad

```
    UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

and also;

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func deviceOrientationDidChange() {
    print(UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue)
    // all return false
    print(UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat)
    print(UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait)
    print(UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape)
    print(UIDevice.current.orientation.isValidInterfaceOrientation)

}
```

I've also tried:

```
UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
```

and all the other possibilities like `.isLandscape`, `.IsFlat`, etc and none of them seem to be working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up getting the information:

```
func deviceOrientation() {
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width < UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
        print("portrait")
    } else {
        print("landscape")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()`. So the device will never send `UIDeviceOrientationDidChange`. And that is also why `UIDevice.current.orientation` doesn't work; it only works if you have called `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()`. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620053-orientation) are quite clear about this.

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange),
            name: .UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
    }
    func deviceOrientationDidChange() {
        print(UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
3
2
4
1
```

Comment: I've updated the post, trimmed it down for a more simplistic read. Still not working :/

Comment: What does the raw value print?

Comment: It only prints 0.

Comment: Well, then you're not sending `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`. It does work and I've added code and output to prove it.

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and it is not working for me. the deviceOrientationDidChange() function is not even being called. Can it be because this is a custom keyboard extension?

Comment: Yes it could. Lots of things don't work in an extension. But of course you never mentioned that in your question. — Just try my code in a normal app view controller and you will see that it does work.

Comment: My apologies, should've mentioned it was an extension.

Comment: Any solution on having this work for an extension? I have full access enabled as well.

Comment: Your question still doesn't mention an extension. I don't think it can work in an extension; as I said, lots of things are forbidden to you in an extension. I've answered the question you actually asked.